# bootstrap constant box within tabbed content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that is using tabs to switch between different content. In that content I have a box of design elements. What I would like to happen though is for that box to stay constant within all the tabs without repeating the html for it six or seven times. Is this possible?

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#design" data-toggle="tab">Cover Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="#video" data-toggle="tab">Video Trailers</a></li>
  <li><a href="#web" data-toggle="tab">Web Banner</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="design">
   <h2>Design Elements</h2>
   <ul>
     <li>This is the content that need to be static</li>
     <li>Skill: I'm skilled!</li>
     <li>Skill: I'm skilled!</li>
     <li>Skill: I'm skilled!</li>
   </ul>
   <p>Content that needs to be switched between tabs</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be wonderful. I only placed one of my tabs above to show an example, If I posted them all then it would be too long to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can accomplish this... bring your static content out of the `.tab-pane` div but still under the `.tab-content` div.  [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/L97Td/)

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <h2>Design Elements</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>This is the content that need to be static</li>
        <li>Skill: I'm skilled!</li>
        <li>Skill: I'm skilled!</li>
        <li>Skill: I'm skilled!</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="design">
        <p>Content that needs to be switched between tabs 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="video">
        <p>Content that needs to be switched between tabs 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="web">
        <p>Content that needs to be switched between tabs 3</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had so many things going every witch way it was getting confusing!